# Trying to understand why my python script is skipping the second row in a csv file

Tags: python, csv

I am putting together a python script to create an output of email addresses from a csv. For whatever reason, the script below is skipping the second row (row after the headers) and only recording the data I need after that row. For example, if the users in the csv file were:

```
Username:
test
admin
root
```

The output would only be:

```
Emails:
admin@gmail.com
root@gmail.com
```

Thus completely ignoring the first entry. Here is the code, any thoughts on the matter are greatly appreciated.

```
for filename in glob.glob(path):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f)
        initialExportOneList = []
        for row in reader:
            iE = [row['Computer Name'], row['Username']]
            finalExportInOneList = [column['Username'] for column in reader if column['Username']]
            initialExportOneList.append(iE)

        domain = '@gmail.com'
        for i in finalExportInOneList:
            fullEmailCreation = i + domain
            print(fullEmailCreation)
```

Comment: `iE = [row['Computer Name'], row['Username']]`: that cannot work with the input file you provided. Can you provide the input file corresponding to the code you posted?

Comment: `finalExportInOneList` is created at each iteration, the effect is: only the last line is considered.

Comment: You're consuming rows from the reader with the `for row in reader` loop, and you're _also_ consuming them with the `[column['Username'] for column in reader if column['Username']]` list comprehension.  Don't do this.

Comment: Ah perfect makes sense, thanks for the help all. Was able to sort it out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You iterate over `reader` *inside* the loop, to get `finalExportInOneList`.

Answer (score 0):

```
for column in reader
```

I am sure you want

```
for column in row
```

Comment: I doubt he does, as he's doing `column['Username']`.